# How to update list of entites by List of dtos in spring boot, data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I just want to know that is there best way to update list of entities which return by id that can update with list of DTO?. For example, I will fetch List of entities by its ID like this.

**My requirement is, If supplierId return list of List then update it is product ID, else insert new record.**

```
List<SupSupplierProduct> list1 = supSupplierProductRepository.findAllBySupplierId(supplierId);
```

I want to update this list with DTO list, `List<SupplierConfigurationResponse> dto`

Entity is

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sup_supplier_product")
public class SupSupplierProduct extends BaseDTO {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "supplier_id")
    private String supplierId;
    @Column(name = "prod_id")
    private String prodId;

}
```

DTO is,

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SupplierConfigurationResponse extends BaseDTO {

    private String prodId;
    
}
```

What I have tried it to get the support of modelMapper. But final output is not what I want.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SupSupplierProduct>>(){}.getType();
        List<SupSupplierProduct> postDtoList = modelMapper.map(dto,listType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map your Entity object to your DTO.

For this, you can use Mapstruct : https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct

With spring data you can fetch your data with stream structure and then map your object before returning it.

Comment: Hi,
I think this is not what I am looking for. I want to know the best way to update list of entities by list of DTOs. if entity not present for DTO it should be an insert.